# An Interview on BBC News or in BBC News

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What is the correct way to write this sentence?
This is for a post on Social Media.

1. Daniel Smith, CEO of TXT Systems, in an interview on BBC News.
2. Daniel Smith, CEO of TXT Systems, in an interview in BBC News.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the context, does the interview appear in a BBC News programme or on the BBC News channel?

Comment: BBC News channel

Comment: In an interview ***with*** [the] BBC News.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Daniel Smith, CEO of TXT Systems, in an interview on BBC News.
> 2. Daniel Smith, CEO of TXT Systems, in an interview in BBC News.

Answer: choice #1.

A person appears *on* TV, not in TV.  He was seen *on* Channel 4, not in Channel 4. And likewise with BBC News.

As a counter-example "He appeared *in* an episode of Seinfeld".  If it's a very particular show. In this case, "on" would also work.